# Complex when on a Camel route

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel

I am new to Camel so I do have a lot of questions.  Before I ask for help I do try to research the issue carefully.  On this issue I just can't find a solution.  It may be the key words are so generic.

I need to have an and condition on the routing.  (SOAP messages)  There are two fields in the header than have to be specific values before the route is used.  How do I specify

```
if(x == 1 and y == 2)
```

using RouteBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use Simple (http://camel.apache.org/simple). You could also look into predicates (http://camel.apache.org/predicate.html).

In XML-DSL it would look like:

```
<choice>
            <when><simple>${header.x} == '1' && ${header.y} == '2'</simple>
                <log message="do something with message"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <log message="do something else"/>
            </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use predicates. Implement the predicate interface and you use the predicate in a choice.

```
from("direct:node1")
                .choice()
                    .when(customPredicate)
                        .to("direct:node2");
```

Predicates are defined exactly for your use case. Predicates help making routing decisions using complex logic embedded in the predicate.